# Need help styling html tables using colspan

Tags: php, html, laravel, html-table

I have dynamic data where it could always change. For example:

This is what I have now:

Sometimes like this:

```
|==============|======|====|====|
|List of people|John  |June|Tom |
|Date Join     |2017  |2018|2016|
|Hobby         |soccer|         |
|Remark        | test test      |
```

And sometime I would get like this:

```
|==============|======|======|=====|
|List of people|John  |June  |Tom  |
|Date Join     |2017  |2018  |2016 |
|Hobby         |soccer|tennis|     |
|Remark        | test test         |
```

I want to make something like this: (is there any way to do it?)

```
|==============|======|====|====|
|List of people|John  |June|Tom |
|Date Join     |2017  |2018|2016|
|Hobby         |     soccer     |
|Remark        | test test      |
```

or like this:

```
|==============|======|====|====|
|List of people|John  |June|Tom |
|Date Join     |2017  |2018|2016|
|Hobby         |  soccer|Tennis |
|Remark        | test test      |
```

Here is the code I used: (this is how I do it for list of people, date and hobby)

```
@foreach($object7 as $val)
    <tr>
      <th style="border: 1px black solid">List of people</th>
      <?php 
            $test = $val->people;
             $testa = rtrim($test, ', ');
            $array =  explode(', ', $testa);
            $count4 = count($array);
       ?>
       @foreach($array as $item)
      @if(($val->people == NULL) || ( $count4 <= 1))
       <td style="border: 1px black solid" colspan="8">
        @else
    <td style="border: 1px black solid" colspan="1">
      @endif
       {{$item}}
    </td>
      @endforeach 
    </tr>
     @endforeach
```

EDIT:
The remark row only has 1 value while the rest can have more than 1 value or more. What I want is based on all this, how can I make all of them the same length?

Answer (score 1):

Try the "colgroup" tag lets try to set their width to make it fix:

```
@foreach($object7 as $val)
<tr>
   <td style="border: 1px black solid" with="40%">List of people</td>
  <?php 
    $test = $val->people;
     $testa = rtrim($test, ', ');
    $array =  explode(', ', $testa);
    $count4 = count($array);
?>

 @foreach($array as $item)
  @if(($val->people == NULL) || ( $count4 <= 1))
      <td style="border: 1px black solid" with="60%">
  @else if($count4 == 2)
      <td style="border: 1px black solid" with="40%">
  @else
    <td style="border: 1px black solid" with="20%">
  @endif
    {{$item}}
    </td>
@endforeach 
</tr>
```

Comment: thanks for replying but the colgroup just make the width increase only. Or do I have to put at the <tr> tag instead if table tag side?

Comment: you can format the size of td with the colgroup remove the colspan.
colspan just state that you will occupy the other span with the number have been indicated. i edited the code and removed the colspan. try it and let me know the result thanks bro

Comment: ow i see it wait for a while

Comment: Hi, I tried removing the colspan and use the colgroup and now those with 3 columns or 2 columns is outside of the table. while those in first column are all align. Sorry but if it is ok with you, can I get back to you in 1 hour time? Going for lunch first

Comment: I need to know about your variables where do you get the values because as i can see here you insert the label ="Date Join" and "Hobby" in the $array variable?

Comment: my variables are from my database so I just use in the controllers something like   $object7 = list_people::where('user_id', $id)->get();

Comment: In my table there are also only 1 value inside. Example, remarks given

Comment: we should have indicator whose the owner of the data. for example:

in remarks who says "test"? what if tom says test in his remarks. then in your code it will just list the remarks.

Comment: if you want chat me on google hangouts so i can help you as far as i can randee.david77@gmail.com

Comment: Hey bro, I think I figured it out, I just made them in a separate table each and from there I just use width:100% and it became exactly what I want. Anyways thank you for your help :)